# Is there a simple and robust way to create a "singleton" process in Bash?

Tags: bash

*Environment: Recent Ubuntu, non-standard packages are OK as long as they are not too exotic.*

I have a data processor bash script that processes data from `stdin`:

```
$ cat data | process_stdin.sh
```

I can change the script.

I have a legacy data producer system (that I can not change) that logs in to a machine via SSH and calls the script, piping it data. Pseudocode:

```
foo@producer $ cat data | ssh foo@processor ./process_stdin.sh
```

The legacy system launches `./process_stdin.sh` a zillion times per day.

I would like to keep `./process_stdin.sh` running indefinitely at `processor` machine, to get rid of process launch overhead. Legacy producer will call some kind of wrapper that will somehow pipe the data to the actual processor process.

Is there a robust unix-way way to do what I want with minimum code? I do not want to change `./process_stdin.sh` (much) — the full rewrite is already scheduled, but, alas, not soon enough — and I can not change data producer.

Comment: My first thoughts on this are that you may have a more difficult time ensuring that your script has a "clean" environment each time it cycles over some input. The process launch that you are trying to avoid does a lot of that, and the script is likely written to assume a clean launch. I'm not saying that the overhead may be excessive in your case, but I would think that through before looking at a method to wrap it and pipe data in.

Comment: not sure if this is a possibility, if you can make the script block on a pipe input, and run in an infinite loop, then its good news, and all you need send the file into the pipe associated with the script, every time you get data, initialize app and run script body. to exit you may sent a keyword for the scrip to leave the main loop.

Comment: The unix way is writing an *init script* and perhaps adding it to some runlevel. BTW [UUOC](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html).

Comment: @bitfiddler Clean environment is not a big deal here — script is rather dumb.

Comment: @n.m.This is pseudocode, instead of cat there is something more complicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A (not so) dirty hack could be the following:

As `foo` on `processor`, create a fifo and run a `tail -f` redirected to *stdin* of `process_stdin.sh`, possibly in an infinite loop:

```
foo@processor:~$ mkfifo process_fifo
foo@processor:~$ while true; do tail -f process_fifo | process_stdin.sh; done
```

Don't worry, at this point `process_stdin.sh` is just waiting for some stuff to arrive on the fifo `process_fifo`. The infinite loop is just here in case something wrong happens, so that it is relaunched.

Then you can send your data thus:

```
foo@producer:~$ cat data | ssh foo@processor "cat > process_fifo"
```

Hope this will give you some ideas!

Comment: This will serialize all processing.  The original did at least allow for parallelism...

Comment: That is OK, parallelism can be achieved by repeating these instructions times the number of CPUs (with separate paths of course). This way it will be less chaotic, BTW, should be more efficient.

Comment: Watch out with this solution! If you really write into the fifo "zillions of times a day", you're likely to occasionally find that your writes interleave. (Even if the low-level write(2) call is atomic, the buffered standard library version isn't, and there is no guarantee that `ssh` will transmit the data in one chunk.)

Answer (score 1):

[Flock](https://linux.die.net/man/1/flock) do the job.

The same command asked 3 times shortly, but waiting until the lock is free.

```
# flock /var/run/mylock -c 'sleep 5 && date' &
[1] 21623
# flock /var/run/mylock -c 'sleep 5 && date' &
[2] 21626
# flock /var/run/mylock -c 'sleep 5 && date' &
[3] 21627
# Fri Jan  6 12:09:14 UTC 2017
Fri Jan  6 12:09:19 UTC 2017
Fri Jan  6 12:09:24 UTC 2017
```